# How to refer to parent component from a Directive in angular 5 using dynamic components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following [this tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms) to create dynamic forms in angular. The [full code for the tutorial is on github](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-dynamic-forms) Everything works nicely, but I want to add something where the parent component, which makes use of a `Directive` with `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically create child components, is able to access the child components.

This is the Directive code:

```js
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Directive, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Type, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { FormButtonComponent } from '../form-button/form-button.component';
import { FormInputComponent } from '../form-input/form-input.component';
import { FormSelectComponent } from '../form-select/form-select.component';

import { Field } from '../../models/field.interface';
import { FieldConfig } from '../../models/field-config.interface';

const components: {[type: string]: Type<Field>} = {
  button: FormButtonComponent,
  input: FormInputComponent,
  select: FormSelectComponent
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamicField]'
})
export class DynamicFieldDirective implements Field, OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input()
  config: FieldConfig;

  @Input()
  group: FormGroup;

  component: ComponentRef<Field>;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private container: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.component) {
      this.component.instance.config = this.config;
      this.component.instance.group = this.group;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!components[this.config.type]) {
      const supportedTypes = Object.keys(components).join(', ');
      throw new Error(
        `Trying to use an unsupported type (${this.config.type}).
        Supported types: ${supportedTypes}`
      );
    }
    const component = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<Field>(components[this.config.type]);
    this.component = this.container.createComponent(component);
    this.component.instance.config = this.config;
    this.component.instance.group = this.group;
    //let parentCmp = ......;
    //parentCmp.addField(this.component.instance);
  }
}
```

Since the `Directive` is where the child components get created, I assume this is where I have access to both the parent and the child, and could pass the child to the parent. This is what I am trying to do with the two commented 
lines in ngOnInit:

```js
let parentCmp = ......;
parentCmp.addField(this.component.instance);
```

This is the component where the directive gets used.

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { FieldConfig } from '../../models/field-config.interface';

@Component({
  exportAs: 'dynamicForm',
  selector: 'dynamic-form',
  styleUrls: ['dynamic-form.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <form
      class="dynamic-form"
      [formGroup]="form"
      (submit)="handleSubmit($event)">
      <ng-container
        *ngFor="let field of config;"
        dynamicField
        [config]="field"
        [group]="form">
      </ng-container>
    </form>
  `
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input()
  config: FieldConfig[] = [];
  fields: object;

  @Output()
  submit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  form: FormGroup;

  get controls() { return this.config.filter(({type}) => type !== 'button'); }
  get changes() { return this.form.valueChanges; }
  get valid() { return this.form.valid; }
  get value() { return this.form.value; }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.createGroup();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.form) {
      const controls = Object.keys(this.form.controls);
      const configControls = this.controls.map((item) => item.name);

      controls
        .filter((control) => !configControls.includes(control))
        .forEach((control) => this.form.removeControl(control));

      configControls
        .filter((control) => !controls.includes(control))
        .forEach((name) => {
          const config = this.config.find((control) => control.name === name);
          this.form.addControl(name, this.createControl(config));
        });

    }
  }

  addField(field){
    this.fields[field.key] = field;
  }

  createGroup() {
    const group = this.fb.group({});
    this.controls.forEach(control => group.addControl(control.name, this.createControl(control)));
    return group;
  }

  createControl(config: FieldConfig) {
    const { disabled, validation, value } = config;
    return this.fb.control({ disabled, value }, validation);
  }

  handleSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.submit.emit(this.value);
  }

  setDisabled(name: string, disable: boolean) {
    if (this.form.controls[name]) {
      const method = disable ? 'disable': 'enable';
      this.form.controls[name][method]();
      return;
    }

    this.config = this.config.map((item) => {
      if (item.name === name) {
        item.disabled = disable;
      }
      return item;
    });
  }

  setValue(name: string, value: any) {
    this.form.controls[name].setValue(value, {emitEvent: true});
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The directive actually has a viewContainetRef injected to get a hold to (component) view container (parent component if you want this way). It (the directive) also has componentFactoryResolver injected to generate component. The dynamically generated component is inserted into its view container (parent component) via containerRef. In your above code, it is "this.container.create...". So what else do you want to implement?

Comment: If I understand you, access parent would be via viewContainerRef (this.container). Access to child would be via componentRef (this.component)

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better, but maybe it helps that I included the parent component now where the directive is used.

Comment: So the DynamicFormComponent includes a bunch of ng-template tags depending on its config attribute. The ng-template includes my directive and instantiates the actual component that is needed using the component factory. Inside this directive, I want to have a reference back to the parent. this.container is the Injecable ViewContainerRef on the directive.

Comment: So what would you want such way for?

Comment: A complex use case where the child components provide methods that I would like to access from the parent component. So the question is: is it possible to somehow send the child components, created in the directive, to the parent component so the parent component can later do stuff with them (like call functions on them)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171955/discussion-between-sugarme-and-dolf-andringa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use an @Output in the Directive. With the output in the Directive, you can create an even emitter to which the parent component can subscribe. That way, the directive can pass data back to the parent component.  In my case I created an output in the directive that passed the child component to it like this:

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, EventEmitter, ComponentRef, Directive, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Type, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamicField]'
})
export class DynamicFieldDirective implements Field, OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input()
  config: FieldConfig;

  @Input()
  group: FormGroup;

  @Output fieldAdded: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  component: ComponentRef<Field>;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private container: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.component) {
      this.component.instance.config = this.config;
      this.component.instance.group = this.group;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!components[this.config.type]) {
      const supportedTypes = Object.keys(components).join(', ');
      throw new Error(
        `Trying to use an unsupported type (${this.config.type}).
        Supported types: ${supportedTypes}`
      );
    }
    const component = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<Field>(components[this.config.type]);
    this.component = this.container.createComponent(component);
    this.component.instance.config = this.config;
    this.component.instance.group = this.group;
    this.fieldAdded.emit(this.component.instance);
  }
}
```

In the parent component I can then bind a function to the output event from the directive, which then handles the child component passed to it, like this:

```js
@Component({
  exportAs: 'dynamicForm',
  selector: 'dynamic-form',
  styleUrls: ['dynamic-form.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <form
      class="dynamic-form"
      [formGroup]="form"
      (submit)="handleSubmit($event)">
      <ng-container
        *ngFor="let field of config;"
        dynamicField
        [config]="field"
        [group]="form"
        (fieldAdded) = "addField($event)"
        >
      </ng-container>
    </form>
  `
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input()
  config: FieldConfig[] = [];
  fields: object = {};

  addField(field: any){
    this.fields[field.key] = field;
  }
```

At that point, the parent component has a this.fields attribute that contains all child component instances and can do stuff with them.